# Find inverse of $7x^{2}-112x+448$

Tags: calculus, inverse, quadratics

Given the function $\; f(x) = 7x^{2}-112x+448, \;$ for $x\ge 8, \;$ find $\displaystyle \;$ $f^{-1}(x)$.

To find inverse, I should just solve for x in terms of y:

$$y = 7x^{2}-112x+448$$

I can rewrite it as:

$$y = (7x-56) (x-8)$$

but what's next?

Or I can also say:

$$y - 448 = 7x (x - 16)$$

and it gets me nowhere ...

p.s. I don't care about signs (e.g., $\; x -8 >= 0$) for now, cuz that's not the hard part

Comment: Write the quadratic as $7(x-8)^2$, that should help.

Comment: @T_M how do you know you'd rewrite it like that

Comment: $7x-56= 7(x-8)$. @Jack

Comment: @T_M how did you know you have to factor out 7? You couldn't have known in advance that you'd get a binomial expansion (a-b)^2 inside parenthesis once you factor out 7

Comment: You wrote that you can rewrite $y=(7x-56)(x-8)$. It follows from what you already knew. @Jack

Comment: @Jack a first instinct on seeing the coefficients is to take 7 common from all of them, and that is why one would do 7(x-8)^2 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can rewrite $7x^2-112x+448=0$ as $7(x-8)^2=0$

Comment: how did you know that?

Comment: You find the discriminant $\Delta=b^2-4ac$, which equals in this case to $0$ and then the double root will be $r=\frac{-b}{2a}$. Then the polynomial can be written as $a(x-r)^2$. @Jack

Answer (score 4):

Following the comments and evinda's answer, you write $y = 7x^2-112x+448$ as $y = 7(x-8)^2$. So to write $x$ as a function of $y$, we take roots and obtain $\sqrt{y} = \sqrt{7} |x-8|$. Without the condition $x \geq 8$ we can't get a single value for $y$ (the function isn't injective in $\Bbb R$). The condition $x \geq 8$ allows us to write $|x-8| = x-8$, and now you can finish it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you're missing a a method called "Completing The Square". Note what happens when we factor out the leading coefficient
$$ax^2+bx+c = a(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a})$$
Now, by multiplying out $(x+t)(x+t)=x^2+2tx+t^2$ we can see that in a perfect square that $\frac{1}{2}$ of the middle coefficient, squared, is equal to the last [constant] coefficient. Applying this model to our original expression we have
$$\begin{array}{lll}
a(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}) &=& a\bigg(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+(\frac{b}{2a})^2+\frac{c}{a}-(\frac{b}{2a})^2\bigg)\\
&=& a\bigg((x+\frac{b}{2a})^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}\bigg)\\
\end{array}$$
In the case where $b^2-4ac=0$, this expression will reduce to
$$a(x-\frac{b}{2a})^2$$

Lets follow these steps with $$y=7x^2-112x+448$$
First, let's factor $7$ from each term
$$y=7(x^2-16x+64)$$
By noting that $\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\cdot (-16)\bigg)^2 = (-8)^2=64$, we know that we already have a perfect square within the parentheses. Half of the middle term ($-16$) is $-8$, so it factors as follows
$$y=7(x-8)^2$$
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to solve the equation:
$$
7x^{2}-112x+(448-y)=0
$$
The roots are
$$
\frac{112+\sqrt{112^2-4\cdot 7(448-y)}}{2\cdot 7}
=8+\frac{\sqrt{7y}}{7}
$$
and the companion
$$
\frac{112-\sqrt{112^2-4\cdot 7(448-y)}}{2\cdot 7}
=8-\frac{\sqrt{7y}}{7}
$$
Since you know that $x\ge8$, only the first root can be used and you get also that the domain of the inverse is $y\ge0$.